# Rewriting a string in AutoIt works once, but not the second time

Tags: windows, network-programming, autoit

I am working on some AutoIt code to help me with office pranks and stuff. The first string works to rewrite the string "shutdown pc00xxx" into `shutdown /r /m pc00xxx /t 0`, but I can't get the second string to re.

I have the following code:

```
func RunProc($string)
    Local $command = StringLower($string)
    Local $subs = StringMid($command, 1, 4)
    Local $computer = StringInStr($command, "pc")

    if $subs == "shut" Then

        Run("shutdown /r /m " & StringMid($command, $computer) & " /t 0")

    ElseIf $subs == "clos" Then

        Local $prleft = StringTrimLeft($command, 6)
        Local $extend = StringInStr($command, "on")
        Local $pright = StringTrimRight($prleft, $extend)
        Local $strclose = StringMid($string, $prleft, $pright)
        Run("taskkill.exe /S "& StringMid($command, $computer) & "  /im " & $strclose & ".exe")
    EndIf
```

The problem is that I am trying to rewrite the phrase "CLOSE "SOMETHING" ON "pc00xxx" to be taskkill.exe /S pc00xxx /im SOMETHING.exe, I am trying to get the substring between "CLOSE " and " ON pc00xxx.

So, for example, I would type CLOSE OUTLOOK ON PC00xxx and have the value of $strclose be:

```
$strclose = outlook
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'CLOSE OUTLOOK ON PC00xxx'
$aMatch = StringRegExp($string, '(?i)close (.+) on pc.+', 1)
If IsArray($aMatch) Then ConsoleWrite('App: ' & $aMatch[0] & @CRLF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use StringSplit:

```
$string = 'CLOSE OUTLOOK ON PC00xxx'
$stringcomponents=StringSplit(StringStripWS($string,4)," ")
$strclose=$stringcomponents
```